# ggplot stat_summary median and boxplot median disagreement

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, statistics

I'm using this

```
ggplot(dfmergedrearrangemelted, aes(x = Var2, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()+
ggtitle("Values and Medians")+xlab(xlabel)+ylab("Magnitude (log10)")+
stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .9),
size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F)+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
scale_x_discrete(labels=namePosTargetGroupV2)+
scale_y_log10()
```

to make a series of boxplots and I've separately labeled the medans with an x through stat_summary. The problem is that the median through stat_summary and the median which is the central line in the boxplot aren't agreeing in all cases. This tends to happen when the box of the boxplot is below 0.1 on a log10 scale. Any idea what the cause is?

Comment: Is it possibly because stat_summary and boxplot calculate median with different precision?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to log10(median), since those are the values computed for the y-axis. At low values, those differences might be seen, but at higher values the log scale appears asymptotic for increasing X, which means - any delta X, will yield a very small delta y.

Comment: But no matter what the scale shouldn't the median for the boxplot match the median for from stat_summary?